# Storing large objects/data on disk to free browser memory in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, caching

I have a situation where I am dealing with very large files and trying to encrypt them.  I am running into a problem in the browser where the browser is running out of memory and so is crashing.

I was hoping to try and offload some of the larger objects/data to a local cache on disk to take these out of memory to help with this.

I've seen the CacheAPI which I thought may help, but this seems to only handle storing requests, whereas I am really dealing with arrays of bytes and objects that I want to store somewhere.

https://web.dev/cache-api-quick-guide/

Is there anything else I can use to support this, I need to support modern browsers so not IE.

Comment: Maybe another approach would be to ask if you really need to handle objects and arrays so large that they overflow the computer's memory? Isn't streaming a solution? Chunking?

Comment: I am chunking before and after the encryption, the issue I have is with the encryption as I can't encrypt in chunks and send up to the server before I go to the next chunk I need to encrypt the whole thing at once.

Answer (score 1):

You can try indexedDB - it supports the data you need.

**https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API**

localStorage size is 5000KB only, when it comes to IndexedDB you are limited by the disk space.

Comment: Ahh this sounds like it could be perfect... I will give it a go this afternoon

Comment: let me know if it helps:)

Comment: It didn't work out, maybe it was me but I couldn't get it to work with large byte arrays, it just kept crashing the browser every time I tried to add a row